# C++ and QT Complicated CSV parsing

Tags: c++, qt, csv, qt5

I have a `.csv` file with some more or less complicated contents.
The main problem is `description` column which contains a long string of text with empty lines, `,` and `"` symbols inside. For example:

```
"NO SAFE PLACE LEFT At great cost to the Garrison and the Survey Corps, Commander Erwin ..."
```

I tried using default C++ and QT tools, but it seems like I need an external library for that.
Those which I found are either outdated or don't have documentation.

I would be grateful if one shared a known and trusted library for csv parsing

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Just use library, for example this one: https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is actively updated: https://github.com/d99kris/rapidcsv

I haven't used it, but a simple search of "csv parsing c++" shows a number of libraries. There might be others that are also actively updated.